# Swift: Getting Thread 1: signal SIGABRT but all of my outlets are connected

Tags: ios, swift

So I'm getting the ever popular Thread 1: signal SIGABRT even though all of my Outlets are connected. I just started building out this table after all of my outlets were fine, and now it keeps breaking.

I know I'm missing something easy/simple, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

I'm copying from another app that I have that works (and is in the App Store), so I'm just not sure what's going on.... Any help is appreciated.

```
import UIKit

class QueenTableViewController: UITableViewController {


    @IBOutlet var queenTable: UITableView!

//MARK: Properties

var queens = [DragQueen]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadSampleQueens()

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return queens.count
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
    let cellIdentifier = "QueenTableViewCell"
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? QueenTableViewCell  else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of QueenTableViewCell.")
    }

    let queen = queens[indexPath.row]


    // Configure the cell...


    cell.QueenNameCell.text = queen.name
    cell.QueenPhotoCell.image = queen.dragPhoto
    cell.QueenValueCell.text = String(queen.ratingTotal)



    return cell
}




//MARK: Private Methods

func loadSampleQueens() {


    let starYellow = UIImage(named: "star-yellow")


     let queen1 = DragQueen(
        name: "Ben Delacreme",
        ratingChar: 4,
        ratingUnique: 4,
        ratingNerve: 4,
        ratingTalent: 4,
        ratingTotal: 5.0,
        isFave: true,
        dragPhoto: starYellow!,
        isLocked: false
    )

    let queen2 = DragQueen(
        name: "Adore Delano",
        ratingChar: 4,
        ratingUnique: 4,
        ratingNerve: 4,
        ratingTalent: 4,
        ratingTotal: 5.0,
        isFave: true,
        dragPhoto: starYellow!,
        isLocked: false
    )

    let queen3 = DragQueen(
        name: "Monique Heart",
        ratingChar: 4,
        ratingUnique: 4,
        ratingNerve: 4,
        ratingTalent: 4,
        ratingTotal: 5.0,
        isFave: true,
        dragPhoto: starYellow!,
        isLocked: false
    )

    queens += [queen1, queen2, queen3]

}

}
```

Here's the QueenTableViewCell class

```
import UIKit

class QueenTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    //MARK: Properties

    @IBOutlet weak var QueenNameCell: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var QueenPhotoCell: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var QueenValueCell: UILabel!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Comment: you are going to have to give some more information. Is there a line it breaks? does it say any other thing?

Comment: The usual suspects: check that "QueenTableViewCell" is correctly set as the identifier for the dynamic cell, check that QueenTableViewCell is set as the class of the dynamic cell, check that the cell outlets are connected correctly, use debugger to check you're getting into the cellForRowAt, check that the UIImage starYellow is found and not null, pin down the line of code that causes the error.

Comment: @gmogames No specific line. Just breaks in the app delegate

Comment: @ces I’ve made sure everything matches up. And I’ve tried breaking all of the things you’re mentioning, and it does break in a different way if I intentionally mess one of those things up.  It’s gotta be something small

Comment: did you enable Exception Breakpoint and Swift Error breakpoint in your breakpoints tab?

Comment: @scttcrry would you please share `QueenTableViewCell ` class?

Comment: @FaysalAhmed Just added to original question

Comment: @gmogames I didn't know those existed until just now. I'll research and see how they work to see if they can help.

Comment: The image `star-yellow` is exist in your project?

Comment: As you are copying from another application, the class names etc might have changed. Remove the outlets in XIB/Storyboard and then add again.

Comment: Disconnect all the outlets, and then re-connect the outlets.

Comment: Missing registerXib? It's unclear from where come the outlet. Specific Cell XIB? You don't have error message in console?

Comment: Apparently I was looking in the wrong console. This is the official error from the console

'Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier QueenTableViewCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by manually adding an identifier for my cell in the storyboard.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code, with a little modification it can compile and show things without crash.

Here is what I did:

- To simplify the process I only keep QueenNameCell in cell. I assume it shouldn't affect the result, but you can try this for debugging further.
- Your QueenTableViewController is a subclass of UITableViewController, and the subclass has its own queenTable? Instead, I changed it to "class QueenTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {". Of course then you need to remove override key words for the delegate methods to be able to compile.

Update: I think your IBOutlet queenTable in QueenTableViewController class might cause the problem as UITableViewController got a property "open var tableView: UITableView!" already. You can either subclass UITableViewController and use the existing tableView or like what I did, subclass UIViewController and conform the protocols "UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource". Then you can use your own tableView IBOutlet there.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean @JohnnL

First bullet: I tried this and nothing happened. Still breaking.

Second bullet: I tried this but I'm not sure what the "remove override...etc" part means?

Comment: ' Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier QueenTableViewCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard' '